# Library using another library

Tags: c++, arduino, libraries

I'm writing library for smart home arduino DIY project.
i want to use another library(not written by me).
here is the code:

boiler.cpp

```
#include "Boiler.h"

Boiler::Boiler(int pin)
{
    _pin = pin;
    dev.setDevice(_pin);                    // Set Device Output (on/off)
    turnOff();
}
```

boiler.h

```
#ifndef BOILER_H_
#define BOILER_H_

// include RF24 libs
#include "RF24.h"
#include "RF24Network.h"
#include "RF24Mesh.h"
#include <SPI.h>

// SmartHome Lib Includes
#include "Device.h"
#include "TimerOne.h"
#include "timeSet.h"



class Boiler 
{

    private:

        RF24 radio(7, 8);
        RF24Network network(radio);
        RF24Mesh mesh(radio, network);

        int _pin ;

        void timerIsr();
        void DrawSCR();
    public:
        .
        .
        .

        Boiler (int pin );
        void turnOn();
        void turnOff();
};
```

The problem is it's not compiling
the error I get is :
Boiler.h: 32:14: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
RF24 radio(7, 8)

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I Have found the answer (by mistake)
i have added the includes to Boiler.cpp file
and moved the

```
   RF24 radio(7, 8);                                    // Init RF24 Radio
   RF24Network network(radio);                          // Init RF24 Network
   RF24Mesh mesh(radio, network);                       // Init RF24 Mesh
```

this is the new code :

```
#include "RF24.h"
#include "RF24Network.h"
#include "RF24Mesh.h"
#include <SPI.h>
.
.
.
#include "Boiler.h"

RF24 radio(7, 8);                                   // Init RF24 Radio
RF24Network network(radio);                         // Init RF24 Network
RF24Mesh mesh(radio, network);                      // Init RF24 Mesh

Boiler::Boiler(int pin ,float Rev , String Last )
{
    _pin = pin;
    dev.setDevice(_pin);                    // Set Device Output (on/off)
    turnOff();
}

void Boiler::init( char nodeID)
{
    _nodeID = nodeID;
    // Connect to the mesh and set Node ID
    mesh.setNodeID(_nodeID);
    if (_DEBUG) Serial.println(F("Connecting to the mesh..."));
    mesh.begin();

    // init LCD and print init data on LCD
    myGLCD.InitLCD(60);                         // Init LCD 55 contrast
    myGLCD.setFont(SmallFont);                  // Set small font
    myGLCD.clrScr();                            // clr screen
    myGLCD.print("Boiler Device",0,0);          //Print init Data on screen
    myGLCD.print("Rev :" , 0 , 10);
    myGLCD.printNumF(_rev,1 ,35,10,'.',1,'0');
    myGLCD.print(_last,0,40);
    myGLCD.update();                            // Update display


    turnOff();
}
```

and now it compiles ;-)

Comment: You also moved `RF24 radio(7, 8);`, fixing the bug.